# How to read file bytes from byte offset?

Tags: c#

If I am given a `.cmp` file and a byte offset `0x598`, how can I read a file from this offset?

I can ofcourse read file bytes like this

```
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("upgradefile.cmp");
```

But how can I read it from byte offset `0x598`

To explain a bit more, actually from this offset the actual data starts that I have to read and before this byte offset it is just header data, so basically I have to read file from that offset till end.

Comment: [FileStream.Seek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.seek) + [FileStream.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.read) (or `.ReadSync()`)

Comment: @Jimi - Actually I was confused with the word `byte offset`, because seek expects position to be passed as `long` type so does it seeks the position basked on bytes?

Comment: Your offset is `0x598`. That's what you pass to the `Seek()` method. Specifying `SeekOrigin.Begin`, of course.

Comment: Microsoft gave us the source of most of .NET. You can see how [File.ReadAllBytes](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,ee8033fcb7e7a677) is implemented, take that code, and change it however you like.

Answer (score 2):

Try code like this:

```
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open("upgradefile.cmp", FileMode.Open)))
        {
            long offset = 0x598;
            if (reader.BaseStream.Length > offset)
            {
                reader.BaseStream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                byte[]fileBytes =  reader.ReadBytes((int) (reader.BaseStream.Length - offset));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with Streams, Linq, or whatever, I have simplest solution for you:

Read entire file into memory (I hope you deal with small files):

```
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("upgradefile.cmp");
```

Calculate how many bytes are present in array after given offset:

```
long startOffset = 0x598; // this is just hexadecimal representation for human, it can be decimal or whatever
long howManyBytesToRead = fileBytes.Length - startOffset;
```

Then just copy data to new array:

```
byte[] newArray = new byte[howManyBytesToRead];

long pos = 0;

for (int i = startOffset; i < fileBytes.Length; i++)
{
    newArray[pos] = fileBytes[i];
    pos = pos + 1;
}
```

If you understand how it works you can look at `Array.Copy` method in Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score -1):

By not using ReadAllBytes.

Get a stream, move to potition, read rest of files.

You basically complain that a convenience method made to allow a one line read of a whole file is not what you want - ignoring that it is just that, a convenience method. The normal way to deal with files is opening them and using a Stream.